# How to disable Copy and Share Menu in Android

Tags: android, cordova, menu, share

First,Apps are written with cordova, So Apps have many web contents.How can I protect contents from  `COPY` and `SHARE` menu for that.I know that Share Menu is globally for all apps, I want to restrict specific for my app.Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use oncopy="return false;" in html tag for disabling copy. If anyone get the solution for disabling share then please share here.